# What determines the element 'mouseover' captures?

Tags: javascript

Does this determine the element `mouseover` will capture with `event.target`?:

The element with the highest `z-index`. If a tie:

The most nested element. If a tie:

The element lowest down in source-order (the element that overlaps).

---

P.s. How would I have found this out from MDN (or another site that isn't the 'specs')?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: @Phix The section 'mouseout when leaving for a child' should make it clear (https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for an explanation about how the foreground element is choosen ?

Comment: @Seblor yes I am

Answer (score 0):

There is no way two elements on the same z-index level share an x-y coordinate, so you can stop at first point, except that you also need to account for their [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) computed rule.

Comment: I'm talking about if the cursor hovers over a space on the website where a parent and child are

Comment: That doesn't change anything, either the parent has an higher z-index, either the child has, they can't have the same. Just take some sheets of paper and try to represent a web page with it, if the sheets share an x-y coordinate, they have to overlap and their z-index have to be different

Comment: Okay, I thought `z-index`'s initial value was `auto` which effectively means zero so both would be zero. Are you saying for elements with `z-index: auto` the parent is considered to have a 'higher z-index'?

Comment: The `z-index` CSS property is just a way to force some ordering, but it's not the only thing that determines the z-index. By default children will have higher z-index than their parents.

Comment: Okay thank-you. 1. Would you be able to pass on something (not 'spec') that talks about 'z-index' in the way you're talking about it here (not directly related to the `z-index` property)? 2. Taking this knowledge to my question, where does 'the element lowest down in source-order' fit in? Is that part of 'z-index'?

Comment: 1. I'm really a "specs-guy" myself and don't trust random blog posts on the web, but for this case, real life and a bit of common sense (if it didn't work that way, browsers would have to draw all the elements with same CSS z-index of in a single call, mixing them in undetermined ways, imagine background images with texts and no way to tell which is in front of which). 2. There is no direct relation, it all depends on the document's stylesheet, but usually children are in front of their parents by default.

Comment: Alright did you get what my question was asking? So basically the element that's captured with `event.target` with `'mouseover'` when the cursor is above multiple elements is the element with the highest z-index?

Comment: Yes, if its `pointer-events` computed rule allows it to be the target of pointer-events. -> What's written in my answer.